# last record in django models database

Tags: python, django, django-models

i am trying to do this:

i have a table of rating records of locations. in this table, one location can also have multiple rating scores. but i want to restrict the search only to the last record of same locations. for example:

one location with `id`=1 has 3 rating scores: 1, 2, 4. now when user searchs for rating score 2, this location should **NOT** appear, because its last record is 4.

**EDIT**
there are two tables(django models): location and rating.

can i do this:

```
all_locations = Location.objects.all()
```

then in template. `locations_rating` is a related_name for foreignkey `locationID` in rating table.

```
{% for location in all_locations %}
  {{ location.locations_rating }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What are your models?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    locationname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.locationname

    def latest(self):
        return Rating.objects.values('rating').filter(von_location=self).order_by('-id')[0]

class Rating(models.Model):
   von_location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_rate")
   rating = models.IntegerField()

   def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.rating)
```

views.py

```
all_locs = Location.objects.all()
```

template

```
{% for location in all_locs %}
   {{ location.locationname }} - {{ location.latest.rating }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: depends on you, you can add that name in the values so that you can access it

Answer (score 1):

This is pure guessing, but can you do something like this?

```
Rating.objects.filter(location_id=1).order_by(id).reverse()[0]
```

Comment: That should be `).order_by('-id')[0]`. Probably also need to wrap in a try/catch in case the count is 0

Comment: @Hamish, yeaaah, that try/catch is very important. but order_by will also give 2 as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I misinterpreted the question. Here's a not very efficient way to do what you're asking:

```
locations = Location.objects.all();
filtered = []
for location in locations:
    try:
        r = Rating.objects.filter(location=location).order_by(-id).[0]
        if r.rating = 2:
        filtered.append(location)
    except Exception as ex:
        pass
```

Comment: This is bad. That's exactly what the Manager is for, so why not use a built-in feature?