# django related manager - in template

Tags: python, database, django, django-related-manager

i am trying to show the latest rating score of a location. i have 2 tables(django models)

```
Class Location(models.Model):
   locationname = models.CharField()
   ...

Class Rating(models.Model):
   von_location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_rate")
   rating = models.IntegerField()
```

now in my db, one location(id=1) has 3 ratings(1,2,4).

i want to show the latest record in rating for a location. can i do this in template using related Manager somehow?

my vision is:

```
all_locs = Location.objects.all()
```

then in template:

```
{% for location in all_locs %}
   {{ location.locations_rate.latest }}
{% endfor %}
```

can relatedmanager do this kind of things?

Comment: just pass it as a parameter to the render template function?

Comment: answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824934/last-record-in-django-models-database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer in your other related question:

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    locationname = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.locationname

    def latest(self):
        return Rating.objects.values('rating').filter(von_location=self).order_by('-id')[0]

class Rating(models.Model):
   von_location = models.ForeignKey(Location,related_name="locations_rate")
   rating = models.IntegerField()

   def __unicode__(self):
        return "{0}".format(self.rating)
```

views.py

```
all_locs = Location.objects.all()
```

template

```
{% for location in all_locs %}
   {{ location.locationname }} - {{ location.latest.rating }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```